# Reasons why retina shauninman .htaccess code is not working on server and how to fix it?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What are the reasons why this specific .htaccess code is not working on my hosting server?
It's working perfectly fine locally, and on many other apache systems. (mod_rewrite is ok with the server)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_RETINA [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !@2x
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1@2x.$2
# if @2x isn't available fulfill the original request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)@2x\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1.$2
</IfModule>
```

Btw. I'm often running into this problem that locally working .htaccess code isn't compatible on a server and I don't understand why that is.

If you're interested in what I was trying to achieve, please go to:
http://shauninman.com/tmp/retina/

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Well, in effect, no images on the website are loading. Please don't hesitate to tell me if you need further info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in my case, the **RewriteBase /** element solved the issue. I'm leaving it there if somebody ever runs in to this issue for shauninmann retina code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} HTTP_IS_RETINA [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !@2x
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1@2x.$2
# if @2x isn't available fulfill the original request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)@2x\.(gif|jpg|png)$ $1.$2
</IfModule>
```